# Convert a DER encoded Certificate to PEM encoded Certificate

Tags: certificates, java, openssl

I have a p7b certificate(DER encoded) which I need to convert to a PEM encoded certificate so that I can import it into my keystore.

I see that the openssl command below does the job of the conversion

```
openssl pkcs7 -in infile.p7b -inform DER -print_certs -outform PEM -out outfile.cer
```

Is there any equivalent keytool command or Java code for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.p7b` file is probably a PKCS#7 encoded certificate chain.

For Java code to pull a single public key from that file, see [Extracting individual .cer certificate from a .p7b file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244860/extracting-individual-cer-certificate-from-a-p7b-file-in-java).

To use keytool to import one or more of the public keys, try [Import PKCS7 (Chained Certificate) using KeyTool command to JKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814569/import-pkcs7-chained-certificate-using-keytool-command-to-jks). As noted, you might have to separate the public keys into individual files and just loop through them.